Cannot get data with multiple indicators from World Bank's API
I am trying to obtain data with multiple indicators from World Bank's API but am unable to do so.
The documentation suggests to use the following format:
http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/chn;ago/indicator/AG.AGR.TRAC.NO;SP.POP.TOTL?source=2
However their very own example returns only data for 'ago' (Angola) and 'AG.AGR.TRAC.NO' (Agricultural machinery, tractors).
The same happens for any request when I try to get multiple indicators. For example http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/us/indicator/BN.CAB.XOKA.CD;BM.GSR.MRCH.CD?source=2&format=json should get the Current account balance and Goods imports of USA but it getting only the former.
At the same time separate requests return data for both indicators:
http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/us/indicator/BN.CAB.XOKA.CD?source=2&format=json  and
http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/us/indicator/BM.GSR.MRCH.CD?source=2&format=json
I am wondering what I might be doing wrong.

The results are paginated. If you look at the results object you will see that you have requested page 1 of 3, with 50 results returned per page and a total of 128 results:
{
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 3,
    "per_page": 50,
    "total": 128,
    "sourceid": null,
    "lastupdated": "2024-05-30"
},

You can get the other results by:

appending page= to the query: http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/us/indicator/BN.CAB.XOKA.CD;BM.GSR.MRCH.CD?source=2&format=json&page=2
Appending per_page= to the query to update how many results the query should return. Per the docs it defaults to 50: http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/us/indicator/BN.CAB.XOKA.CD;BM.GSR.MRCH.CD?source=2&format=json&per_page=128


Hey, thanks a lot for this! It would have helped if they had mentioned that in the documentation for the example they have provided.

No problem, it's something you get used to with API's with potentially large datasets, esp financial data. Pretty much expect all financial api's to have pagination and just look for "page" related keywords in their docs.
